# pandas read csv with extra commas in column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading a basic csv file where the columns are separated by commas with these column names:

`userid, username, body`

However, the body column is a string which may contain commas.  Obviously this causes a problem and pandas throws out an error:

`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 8`

Is there a way to tell pandas to ignore commas in a specific column or a way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Imagine we're reading your dataframe called `comma.csv`:

```
userid, username, body
01, n1, 'string1, string2'
```

One thing you can do is to specify the delimiter of the strings in the column with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('comma.csv', quotechar="'")
```

In this case strings delimited by `'` are considered as total, no matter commas inside them.

Comment: I don't think his string has quotes, because if it did then pandas would recognize it without `quotechar`

Comment: Like Leb said, I don't have quotes around the body

Comment: @David Ok got it. Your dataframe has been provided "as is", or you can do some preprocessing on it?

Comment: @Fabio: dataframe is an output of a hive SQL query. I then replace the default tab delimiter with ",".  I tried to avoid replacing the tab delimiter and keeping it as is, trying to do `pd.read_csv(...., sep='\t')` but it turns out that some `body` fields have tabs in them as well, so it's all just a mess.

Comment: @David have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14550441/2699288) question, hope that can help you.

Comment: @David Why no import straight from the SQL, maybe something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193/how-to-convert-sql-query-result-to-pandas-data-structure

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your feedback. I figured it out with @Fabio's suggested question.

Comment: I tried this example, but does not work for me. Python 3, pandas 0.18.0 reads `comma.csv` but `01` become the index `1`, and `username` become only `'string1` :(

Comment: Does NOT work in pandas 1.5.3
It parses the first column as index and the comma separated qouted string as  two columns

Answer (score 19):

Add usecols and lineterminator to your read_csv() function, which, n is the len of your columns.

In my case:

```
n = 5 #define yours
df = pd.read_csv(file,
                 usecols=range(n),
                 lineterminator='\n',
                 header=None)
```

Comment: Helped with my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

for me none of the above code samples worked (I was working on Netflix Prize dataset on Kaggle) but there is actually one cool feature from pandas version 1.3.0+ which an `on_bad_lines` parameter that let you use a callback function. Here is what I did:

```py
def manual_separation(bad_line):
    right_split = bad_line[:-2] + [",".join(bad_line[-2:])] # All the "bad lines" where all coming from the same last column that was containing ","
    return right_split

filename = "netflix_movie_titles.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(
        filename, 
        header=None,
        encoding="ISO-8859-1",
        names = ['Movie_Id', 'Year', 'Name'], 
        on_bad_lines=manual_separation,
        engine="python",
    )
```

Works like a charm! Your only obligation is to use `engine=python`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
import csv
with open("csv_with_commas.csv", newline='', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    csvread = csv.reader(f)
    batch_data = list(csvread)
    print(batch_data)
```

Reference:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477760/6907424

[2] To combat "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 157: character maps to undefined": https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233174/6907424

Answer (score 0):

> First, I didn't find anything to resolve "comma inside qoutes, issue"
> systematically and properly. The pandas=1.5.3 is unable to parse it
> correctly. Tried to specify parameters like qoutechar, quoting,
> escapechar, lineterminator, ...

Finally, found two workaround solutions taking advantage I know the comma could be in the last column only.
Assume following content of csv

```
userid, username, body
1, Joe, string1
2, Jim, "string21, string22"
```

If you don't mind the part after 3rd comma is lost then specify number of columns

```
pd.read_csv(r'c:\TEMP\to_parse.csv',usecols=range(3))
```

which yields

```
   userid  username        body
0       1       Joe     string1
1       2       Jim   "string21
```

Second workaround is more complicated but it yields complete string with comma. The principle is to replace first 2 commas by semicolon (you must know the number of columns)

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    fo = io.StringIO()
    data = f.readlines()
    fo.writelines(u"" + line.replace(';', ':').replace(',', ';', 2) for line in data)
    fo.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(fo, on_bad_lines='warn', sep=';')
```

Perhaps it could be accomplished by regex as well.

Comment: Hi @karel-marik, you might want to try adding the `skipinitialspace=True` option to `read_csv` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311951/10201982)). This helped me to get an example like yours to work with pandas.