# Reading strings from csv does not print \n

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, newline

Im reading strings from a csv file. These strings contain "\n" chars to represent new lines.
How can I print these strings with the correct new lines? Using str() didn't work.

CSV File has only one line:

```
Dest, Test\n Test2\n Test3
```

The code below prints `Test\n Test2\n Test3`

```
for ifile in files:
    with open(orderPath + '\\' + ifile) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_reader:

            dest = row[0]
            message = row[1]

            message = str(message)
            print(message)
```

Comment: Can you try passing the newline='' parameter in the open() function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify Newline character ('\n') in reading csv using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476677/specify-newline-character-n-in-reading-csv-using-python)

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Comment: How is the one line in the csv file supposed to be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear precisely how you want the data in the csv file to be interpreted, but here's a guess. It uses the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to convert the escape characters in the input data into newline characters.

This involves enclosing the second column in *triple* double-quotes (`"""`) characters to allow it to interpreted as Python string literal. Triple quotes are used in case the enclosed text itself contains quotes. For example: `Dest, Test\n "Test2"\n Test3`

```
import ast
import csv

filename = 'one_line.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
        dest = row[0]
        message = ast.literal_eval('"""{}"""'.format(row[1]))
        print(dest)
        print(message)
```

Output:

```
Dest
 Test
 Test2
 Test3
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace the sequence of literal characters '\' and 'n' in your input with newlines:

Instead of:

```
message = str(message)
```

You want:

```
message = message.replace('\\n', '\n')
```