# pandas read_csv can't handle additional commas in double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Seems like this has been addressed so many times, yet I'm not able to resolve it.
Here's a minimal example of my CSV:

```
Issue, Content
Test, "A, B"
Test, "A, B, C"
```

Here's the read_csv code (tried all sorts of combinations regarding parameters):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=",", quotechar='"', encoding="utf-8")
```

Here's the error:
ParserError:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4

I created the CSV file with a plain text editor. Wondering also why the interpreter expects 3 fields..

Comment: change your syntax to : df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, encoding="utf-8")

Comment: thx, but didn't help..

Comment: Your CSV is invalid, there shouldn't be a space between the delimiter and the quotes, use `skipinitialspace=True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=",", quotechar='"', skipinitialspace = True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: you might want to explain why, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042924/pandas-read-csv-cant-handle-additional-commas-in-double-quotes#comment135817338_77042924) ;)

Answer (score 0):

For what you need the delimiter in this case?

If you follow the post [pandas read csv with extra commas in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743479/pandas-read-csv-with-extra-commas-in-column) , it should be:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', quotechar="'", encoding="utf-8", sep=",")
```